# Reactor - how to buffer messages received in a Rest POST method

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, project-reactor

I am new to Reactor   and I am trying to update an existing Spring rest service to wait to receive 100 messages or until the time exceeds 30 seconds since the last save before to save myreceived messages.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) 
public void create(@RequestBody String reqJsonString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    Flux.just(json).bufferTimeout(100, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()).subscribe(list -> {

        LOG.info("size:”+list.size());
        this.save(list);

    });
}
```

But the list contains only one message even if I am sending hundred of messages to the rest service.
How can I buffer POST messages in a list before to save them in one batch?

Comment: @Michael Petch I am not sure why you are mentioning me, I did not ask the question and I did not add the tags

Comment: @MichaelPetch Nope, I think we edited simultaneously and I did not remove or add any tags. So it's a case of dirty read error in stack overflow. Anyway, all the best in reviewing and editing.

Answer (score 2):

Got your idea, for that purpose you would need something like shared `Processor` which will be responsible for receiving result:

```
class MyController {    
   private Sink<String> sink;

   MyController() {
      Flux.<String>push(sink -> this.sink = sink)
          .bufferTimeout(100, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
          .publishOn(Schedulres.elastic())
          .subscribe(list -> {

            LOG.info("size:”+list.size());
            this.save(list);

          });
   }



    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) 
    public void create(@RequestBody String reqJsonString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        sink.onNext(reqJsonString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand what you want to do, but everytime you call Flux.just(json), you create a new Flux of one item.

You'd have to create a publisher and call onNext for every json. The subscribe() part would then not be on the POST handling.

Here is a simple example I created from the documentation (sorry for my sloppiness)

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.UnicastProcessor;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {

    private UnicastProcessor<String> hotSource = UnicastProcessor.create();
    private Flux<String> hotFlux = hotSource.publish().autoConnect();


    public void nextItem(String string){
        hotSource.onNext(string);
    }

    public void complete(){
        hotSource.onComplete();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Test test = new Test();

        // simulate POST calls executed in //
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(5));
        threadPoolExecutor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                //Should get the first two before the first 2s
                test.nextItem("First");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                test.nextItem("Second");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //Should get a single element, since 2.5s will pass between 3rd and 4th
                test.nextItem("Third");
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                //Should get a single element, and the complete
                test.nextItem("Fourth");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                test.complete();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        test.hotFlux.bufferTimeout(2, Duration.ofMillis(2000))
        .subscribe(
                list -> System.out.println("Got: " + Arrays.toString(list.toArray()))
        );

        threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK) 
public void create(@RequestBody String reqJsonString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    Flux.just(json).bufferTimeout(100, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
    .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()).subscribe(list -> {

        LOG.info("size:”+list.size());
        this.save(list);

    });
}
```